# SQL Sum(Count) of specific columns and group SUM by Month

Tags: sql, sum

So i have a bunch of data, and i already have it grouped by The column name and month.
Here is the SQL query i have so far

TestName is a column name, POE Business Rules/Submit occur many times per column
VExecutionGlobalHistory is the name of the table,
Im using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010

```
    select  
   year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)),
    datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)),TestName,

    Case WHEN Testname = 'POE Business Rules' THEN (count(TestName)*36) WHEN TestName =         'Submit' THEN (count(TestName)*6) ELSE 0 END

    From VExecutionGlobalHistory

    group by
    year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)),
    datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)),TestName
```

This query gives me this format

```
  2013 |APRIL| POE Business Rules| 1044
  2013 |APRIL| SUBMIT            | 96
  2013 |JULY | POE Business Rules| 216
  2013 |JULY | SUBMIT            | 102
```

I would like to have a final format where it has only each month with the sum of the counts

```
   2013|APRIL|SUM of the counts or (1044 + 96)
   2013|JULY |SUM of the counts or (216 + 102)
```

I dont need the testname just the sum of the counts per month

I have tried adding SUM right before case but i get 
`"Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."` Error.

Any suggestions on another approach?

Comment: Why are you using `year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0))` instead of just `year(StartTime)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a subquery:

```
SELECT Year_, Month_, SUM(Counts)
FROM (
        SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,StartTime),0))'Year_'
              ,DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,StartTime),0))'Month_'
              ,TestName
              ,CASE WHEN Testname = 'POE Business Rules' THEN (count(TestName)*36) 
                    WHEN TestName = 'Submit' THEN (COUNT(TestName)*6) 
                    ELSE 0 
               END 'Counts'
        FROM VExecutionGlobalHistory
        GROUP BY YEAR(DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,StartTime),0))
                ,DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,0,StartTime),0))
                ,TestName
        )sub
GROUP BY Year_, Month_
ORDER BY CAST(CAST(Year_ AS CHAR(4)) + Month_ + '01' AS DATETIME)
```

Update:  Added ORDER BY to sort by YEAR/MONTH  oldest first.

Comment: This works great, the only problem i have now is the months are ordered alphabetically. I would like them to be listed by the month in order. Before i was ordering by order by
 dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0), year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)). 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Error "Type DATE is not a defined system type." I dont know why it would say this?

Comment: Oh, what RDBMS are you using?  I always think in SQL Server.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010

Comment: Odd, try DATETIME instead of DATE.

Comment: How would i get rid of the year and just have month and a number?
Nevermind got it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Select SumYear,SomeMonth,Sum(SumCounts) From
(
select  
   year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)) as SumYear,
    datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)) as SumMonth,TestName,

    Case WHEN Testname = 'POE Business Rules' THEN (count(TestName)*36) WHEN TestName =         'Submit' THEN (count(TestName)*6) ELSE 0 END as sumCounts

    From VExecutionGlobalHistory

    group by
    year(dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)),
    datename(month,dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,0,StartTime),0)),TestName ) sums
Group by SumYear,SumMonth
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

Your logic may be overcomplicated.  It sounds like you just want a weighted sum grouped by (year,month).  Rows with 'POE Business Rules' are worth 36, rows with 'Submit' are worth 6, and all others are worth 0.

```
SELECT
  YEAR(StartTime),
  DATENAME(month,DATEADD(month,MONTH(StartTime)-1,0)),
  SUM(
    CASE Testname
      WHEN 'POE Business Rules' THEN 36
      WHEN 'Submit'             THEN 6
      ELSE 0
    END
  )
FROM VExecutionGlobalHistory
GROUP BY YEAR(StartTime),MONTH(StartTime)
ORDER BY YEAR(StartTime),MONTH(StartTime)
```